# Three and four images with captions in a Beamer frame

Tags: beamer, graphics, captions, columns

I have often used two columns and two images side by side in Beamer frame. But I could not get three one large and second column contains two small images or four images with captions in a single Beamer frame. Can someone help.

```
\documentclass[slidestop,compress,11pt,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\definecolor{LHCblue}{RGB}{4, 114, 255}
\usecolortheme[named=LHCblue]{structure}
\usepackage[bars]{beamerthemetree} % Beamer theme v 2.2
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{marvosym}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{columns}[t]
\column{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=3.5cm]{example-image-golden}\\
\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=4cm]{example-image-golden}
\column{.5\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=4cm]{example-image-golden}\\
\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=4cm]{example-image-golden}
\end{columns}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Of course we can help you, but with one condition: add to your question the MWE which will show your problem. Without it we can only keep finger crossed for you ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `width=\columnwidth` and load package `caption`:

```
\begin{frame}
    \begin{columns}[t]
        \column{.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth,height=3cm]{example-image-golden}
        \captionof{figure}{foo}
        \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth,height=3cm]{example-image-golden}
        \captionof{figure}{bar}
        \column{.5\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth,height=3cm]{example-image-golden}
        \captionof{figure}{foo}
        \includegraphics[width=\columnwidth,height=3cm]{example-image-golden}
        \captionof{figure}{bar}
    \end{columns}
\end{frame}
```

[image]

Comment: how do you add caption for each image ?

Comment: see edited answer